# How do I fix this animation?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

The goal of this card animation is that they get bigger when you hover over them. But right now, when you hover over one card, all the other cards get bigger too, which is not what I want. I need to figure out how to make it so only the card you're actually hovering over gets bigger, and the others stay the same.

```
HTML:

<div class="card-container" style="margin-top: -25rem; gap: auto">
  <div class="card  col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
        <div class="img">
                    <img src="img/logoalpinestars.png" alt="logo alpinestars" style="transform: scale(0.2);">
                </div>

                <div class="content">
                    <span class="desc text-white">A Alpinestars, criada em
                        1963, é a marca líder
                        mundial em tecnologia de
                        proteção paira prática de
                        esportes à motor. A
                        empresa acredita que o
                        melhor design é fruto do
                        aprendizado obtido sob
                        condições extremas.</span>
                </div>

                <div class="arrow">
                    <span>&#8673;</span>
                </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card  col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
        <div class="img">
            <img src="img/logoasw.png" alt="logo alpinestars" style="transform: scale(0.3);">
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <span class="desc text-white">A Alpinestars, criada em
                1963, é a marca líder
                mundial em tecnologia de
                proteção paira prática de
                esportes à motor. A
                empresa acredita que o
                melhor design é fruto do
                aprendizado obtido sob
                condições extremas.</span>
        </div>

                <div class="arrow">
                    <span>&#8673;</span>
                </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
    <div class="img">
        <img src="img/logobell.png" alt="logo alpinestars" style="transform: scale(0.06);">
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <span class="desc text-white">A Alpinestars, criada em
            1963, é a marca líder
            mundial em tecnologia de
            proteção paira prática de
            esportes à motor. A
            empresa acredita que o
            melhor design é fruto do
            aprendizado obtido sob
            condições extremas.</span>
    </div>

                <div class="arrow">
                    <span>&#8673;</span>
                </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
    <div class="img">
        <img src="img/leattlogo.png" alt="logo alpinestars" style="transform: scale(0.2);">
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <span class="desc text-white">A Alpinestars, criada em
            1963, é a marca líder
            mundial em tecnologia de
            proteção paira prática de
            esportes à motor. A
            empresa acredita que o
            melhor design é fruto do
            aprendizado obtido sob
            condições extremas.</span>
    </div>

                <div class="arrow">
                    <span>&#8673;</span>
                </div>
  </div>
</div>


css:

.card-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px;
}

.card {
  border-radius: 16px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: calc(25% - 20px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#b8b4b4, #b8b4b4);
  transition: all 0.5s;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.card:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#080434, #080434);
}

.card .img {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.card .img span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: italic;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.card:hover .img {
  width: 110%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.card:hover .img span {
  font-size: 28px;
}

.card .content {
  padding: 0px 20px;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateY(30px);
}

.card:hover .content {
  height: 260px;
  padding: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.card .content p {
  margin: 0;
}

.card .content .title {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.card .content .desc {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 100;
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.card .arrow {
  padding: 15px;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.card:hover .arrow {
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.card .arrow span {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

I have tried creating different classes for each card to animate, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

add `transform:scale(1.1);` on your `card:hover`